# Error message "Still can't get my hands on win32ui" when setting up new Django project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pywin32

I am currently setting up Django on my Windows 10 system and after having installed it successfully, I am now facing an error message when trying to start a new Django project.

I have created a new directory for my project, gone to the command line and changed the directory to this new folder path and then typed the command:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

but I get a pop up window with the error message:

```
"Still can't get my hands on win32ui"
```

As I understand it, win32ui is a module contained within pywin32 - so I have gone and checked that pywin32 is correctly installed on my laptop - which it is as:

```
pip install pywin32
```

results in:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pywin32 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

I've searched Google and StackOverflow but there isn't a single hit for this error message in relation to new Django projects.

Could anyone shed some light on how I can successfully get a new Django project set up?

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32), to install pywin32 system files, run `python.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install` from an **elevated** command prompt.

For example, this works for me: `"C:\Programs\Python\Python3\CPython\x64\Python35\python.exe" "C:\Programs\Python\Python3\CPython\x64\Python35\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py" -install`.

Comment: This worked, even though I didn't run it in elevated command prompt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Python can't properly locate the libraries you're trying to import. Doing a clean python install may solve the issue. However, instead of doing that, you could try the following:

I've seen this problem happen before when a python installation failed to copy `pywintypes27.dll` and `pythoncom27.dll` to the `win32` folder, please try doing this:

- Go to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32`
- Copy `pywintypes27.dll` and `pythoncom27.dll`
- Paste them in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32`

For future reference, if this works, how did you install Python?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I have just tried this and it has not fixed the problem. For reference, I did a manual install of Python 2.7 from the python.org site and then pip installed lots of additional libraries that I am using.

Comment: If I was to delete my current installation of Python and replace it with an installation of the Anaconda package - do you think that may solve my problem?

Comment: I can't guarantee that it'll work, but I have installed Anaconda and I had no problems with django. You may also want to check [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Python/Q_27697673.html), where someone had the same problem as you.

Comment: Thanks - So I went in to Advanced System Settings and added and Environment Variable with Variable = "PYTHON_PATH" and Value "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com" but I am still getting the same error message. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Yes, according to that link, that was a possible solution. To be honest, at this point I don't really know why it isn't working.

Comment: Well I've deleted a path variable by mistake and now it says django isn't even a recognised variable or something when I try to start a new "mysite". I give up....nothing ever works properly, can't be bothered anymore. Thanks for your efforts though, very much appreciated.